# Extend activity or listactivity?

Tags: java, android

Ok guys, so as an Android newbie Im working my way through various things. My issue here is Im trying to start a new intent activity in a 'onListItemClick'. I have the method set up for this but when i run the AVD upon clicking the item in the list, nothing happens, the intent doesn't start.

If I change the the super class to 'ListActivity' I get a crash message of 'your content must have a listview whose id attribute is 'android.r.id.list''

Can anyone tell me why the intent wont start from clicking the item in the listview?
Here's my listview class:

```
package com.example.sqliteexample;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SQLView extends ListActivity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    HotOrNot H = new HotOrNot(this, null, null);

    setContentView(R.layout.layout);
    ListView listContent = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contentList);

    HotOrNot Content = new HotOrNot(this, null, null);
    Content.open();
    Cursor cursor = Content.getData();

    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    String [] from = new String [] {H.KEY_NAME, H.KEY_HOTNESS};
    int [] to = new int [] {R.id.txtName, R.id.txtAge};

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.entries, cursor, from, to);

    listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
 }


public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int posistion, long id)
{

    Intent i = new Intent("com.example.sqliteexample.SQLiteExample");

    startActivity(i);
}




}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're gonna use a `ListActivity` then you don't need this line:

```
ListView listContent = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contentList);
```

**BUT** that specific `ListView` being referred to right now (provided it's in the corresponding xml layout) must have it's id changed to

```
<ListView
  android:id="@android:id/list"
.....
```

Comment: mango, have you got any idea why when i change my id to this, i cant get my R file back?

Comment: try cleaning your project. honestly the reason could for any particular reason, most probably a mis-spelling. you can look in this post for any ideas that you haven't thought of yet. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error

Answer (score 0):

> I get a crash message of 'your content must have a listview whose id
>   attribute is 'android.r.id.list''

This happenes when you extend `ListActivity` but there is no attribute list in xml (in your case layout.xml). Read [this example on how to create ListActivity](http://www.learn-android.com/2009/12/05/lots-of-lists-1-simple/).

> Extend activity or listactivity?

Answer for this question depends on your requirements.

Comment: Hi Nambari. When you say no 'attribute' do you mean the id of the listview?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your layout.xml file adjust your ListView element to have something similar to below: the most important is `android:id` line

```
<ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Javacadabra, if i do that (which i have done in the past, then its not recognized in my sqlView class?

Comment: Mangos answer above should work. You don't need to create a new list. By extending to ListActivity your Activity will no by default which list you want to use, providing you assign it the id of "list" in the xml.

Answer (score 0):

```
listContent.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long id) {

                Intent i = new Intent("com.example.sqliteexample.SQLiteExample");
                startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Activity - Use for normal purpose
ListActivity - Use where your more concentration is on displaying the lists.

Advantages of ListActivity over Activity:

1. If there is only textual display of list then there is even no need of defining layout file and hence no `setContentView()` to call.
2. If we need to display something else(say TextView) other than list alone then in layout file, just use @android:id/xxx and layout resource parameter `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` in Adapter will correspond to this list defined in xml.
3. Instead of first defining list and then calling `setAdapter()` on it, just call `setListAdapter()` directly.
4. There is no need to implement OnClickListener, `setOnClickListener()` on list and then use `onItemClick()`. Just use `onListItemClick()`.